# Oracle - group by of joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I tried to look for an answer and I found more advices, but not anyone of them was helpful, so I'm trying to ask now.
I have two tables, one with distributors (columns: distributorid, name) and the second one with delivered products (columns: distributorid, productid, corruptcount, date) - the column corruptcount contains the number of corrupted deliveries. I need to select the first five distributors with the most corrupted deliveries in last two months. I need to select distributorid, name and sum of corruptcount, here is my query:

`SELECT del.distributorid, d.name, SUM(del.corruptcount) AS corrupt
    FROM distributor d, delivery del
   WHERE d.distributorid = del.distributorid
     AND d.distributorid IN
       (SELECT distributorid
          FROM (SELECT distributorid, SUM(corruptcount) AS corrupt
                  FROM delivery
                 WHERE storeid = 1
                   AND "date" BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2) AND SYSDATE
                   AND ROWNUM <= 5
              GROUP BY distributorid
              ORDER BY corrupt DESC))
GROUP BY del.distributorid`


But Oracle returns error message: "not a GROUP BY expression".
And when I edit my query to this:

`SELECT del.distributorid, d.name, del.corruptcount-- , SUM(del.corruptcount) AS corrupt
    FROM distributor d, delivery del
   WHERE d.distributorid = del.distributorid
     AND d.distributorid IN
       (SELECT distributorid
          FROM (SELECT distributorid, SUM(corruptcount) AS corrupt
                  FROM delivery
                 WHERE storeid = 1
                   AND "date" BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2) AND SYSDATE
                   AND ROWNUM <= 5
              GROUP BY distributorid
              ORDER BY corrupt DESC))
--GROUP BY del.distributorid`


It's working as you expect and returns correct data:
`1  IBM   10
2  DELL  0
2  DELL  1
2  DELL  6
3  HP    3
8  ACER  2
9  ASUS  1`

I'd like to group this data. Where and why is my query wrong? Can you help please? Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just the `d.name` in the `select` list; you need to include it in the `group by` clause as well.  Try this:

```
SELECT del.distributorid, d.name, SUM(del.corruptcount) AS corrupt
FROM distributor d join
     delivery del
     on d.distributorid = del.distributorid
WHERE d.distributorid IN
             (SELECT distributorid
              FROM delivery
              WHERE storeid = 1 AND
                    "date" BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2) AND SYSDATE AND
                    ROWNUM <= 5
              GROUP BY distributorid
              ORDER BY SUM(corruptcount) DESC
             ) 
GROUP BY del.distributorid, d.name;
```

I also switched the query to using explicit `join` syntax with an `on` clause, instead of the outdated implicit `join` syntax using a condition in the `where`.

I also removed the additional layer of subquery.  It is not really necessary.

EDIT:

"Why does d.name have to be included in the `group by`?"  The easy answer is that SQL requires it because it does not know which value to include from the group.  You could instead use `min(d.name)` in the `select`, for instance, and there would be no need to change the `group by` clause.

The real answer is a wee bit more complicated.  The ANSI standard does actually permit the query as you wrote it.  This is because `id` is (presumably) declared as a primary key on the table.  When you group by a primary key (or unique key), then you can use other columns from the same table just as you did.  Although ANSI supports this, most databases do not yet.  So, the real reason is that Oracle doesn't support the ANSI standard functionality that would allow your query to work.

Comment: Thank you for the correction of my query, I didn't know about outdated implicit join syntax and ordering by SUM... good idea, thnx. And why d.name should be included in the GROUP BY clause?

_Edit: Thank you for explanation. Oracle found one error, ordering by SUM(corruptcount) not working, Oracle returns: "missing right parenthesis"_